# How to use VS2010 publishing to add write access to a folder for Network Service?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I need to ensure some upload directories always have write access for Network Service. I created a ProjectName.wpp.targets XML file containing configuration to add this in during the publishing process in Visual Studio 2010 but it doesn't seem to work. There are no errors but write access is not applied. I restart VS after any change, so it's not caching a previous version. Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="SetupCustomAcls" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">
        <ItemGroup>
            <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
                <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\Assets\Uploads\FirstFolder</Path>
                <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
                <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
                <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
            </MsDeploySourceManifest>
            <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
                <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\Assets\Uploads\SecondFolder</Path>
                <setAclUser>NETWORK SERVICE</setAclUser>
                <setAclAccess>Read,Write</setAclAccess>
                <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
                <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclUser;setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
            </MsDeploySourceManifest>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" AfterTargets="AddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems">
        <ItemGroup>
            <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="FirstFolderSetAclParam">
                <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
                <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
                <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\Assets\\Uploads\\FirstFolder$</Match>
                <Description>Add write permission to the FirstFolder.</Description>
                <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/Assets/Uploads/FirstFolder</DefaultValue>
                <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/Assets/Uploads/FirstFolder</Value>
                <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
                <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
                <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
            </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
            <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="SecondFolderSetAclParam">
                <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
                <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
                <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\Assets\\Uploads\\SecondFolderFuelBills$</Match>
                <Description>Add write permission to the SecondFolder.</Description>
                <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/Assets/Uploads/SecondFolder</DefaultValue>
                <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/Assets/Uploads/SecondFolder</Value>
                <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
                <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
                <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
            </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I am publishing to a network file share, so perhaps that is something as all the examples I can find (not many) are concerned with IIS.

How to get Network Service writing to those directories? Do I need to explicitly add something in the project properties?

Richard